# Changing a label from a wordpress plugin with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to use a custom javascript plugin to change a label from another plugin but not being able to do it.

```
<li class="birs_form_field birs_client_name_last">
<label>Sobrenome</label><div class="birs_field_content">
<input id="birs_client_name_last" name="birs_client_name_last" type="text"> 
<input type="hidden" name="birs_client_fields[]" 
value="_birs_client_name_last"></div><div class="birs_error" 
id="birs_client_name_last_error"></div></li>
```

I just want to change the label "Sobronome" to "Empresa". The following code did not work.

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementsByClassName('birs_form_field birs_client_name_last').innerHTML = 'Empresa';
}
```

I've also tryied with innerText and value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently doing the following wrong:

`getElementsByClassName` does return a NodeList not a single element. A nodelist is a collection of elements and therefore does not have a `innerText` property. Here is one way you could fix it:

```js
const label = document.querySelector('.label');

label.innerText = 'Empresa';
```

```html
<label  class="label">Sobrenome</label>
```

1. Add a class or something to select the element with to the label
2. Change the innertext property.